# Make Total in Pivot Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Below is my query

```
SELECT UserName ,
       TotCount ,
       EntryDate
FROM   @CandidateCount AS cc
```

and output of above query is

```
UserName   TotCount   EntryDate
--------------------------------
neelam       2        17/12/2013
neelam       1        18/12/2013
neelam       6        19/12/2013
snehal       7        17/12/2013
snehal       0        18/12/2013
snehal       2        19/12/2013
```

I have updated above query

```
 SELECT *
 FROM   ( SELECT    EntryDate ,
                UserName ,
                TotCount
          FROM      @CandidateCount AS tbl
        ) AS SourceTable PIVOT
    ( SUM(TotCount) FOR UserName IN ( [neelam], [snehal] ) )AS PivotTable
 ORDER BY EntryDate DESC
```

and output of above query is

```
  EntryDate    neelam    snehal
  19/12/2013     6        2
  18/12/2013     1        0
  17/12/2013     2        7
```

Now i want to make total datewise like this

```
 EntryDate    neelam    snehal    Total
 19/12/2013     6         2        8
 18/12/2013     1         0        1
 17/12/2013     2         7        9
```

How can i do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've put your data inside a CTE named `Source` to give you an example. With another CTE you can easily put your totals aside. You can later join these totals on both EntryDates:

```
WITH Source AS (
    SELECT 'neelam' AS UserName, 2 AS TotCount, '17/12/2013' AS EntryDate UNION
    SELECT 'neelam' AS UserName, 1 AS TotCount, '18/12/2013' AS EntryDate UNION
    SELECT 'neelam' AS UserName, 6 AS TotCount, '19/12/2013' AS EntryDate UNION
    SELECT 'snehal' AS UserName, 7 AS TotCount, '17/12/2013' AS EntryDate UNION
    SELECT 'snehal' AS UserName, 0 AS TotCount, '18/12/2013' AS EntryDate UNION
    SELECT 'snehal' AS UserName, 2 AS TotCount, '19/12/2013' AS EntryDate
)

, Totals AS (
    SELECT      EntryDate
                    , SUM(TotCount) AS Total
    FROM        Source
    GROUP BY    EntryDate
)

SELECT PivotTable.*
       , Totals.Total
 FROM   ( SELECT    EntryDate ,
                UserName ,
                TotCount
          FROM      Source AS tbl
        ) AS SourceTable PIVOT
    ( SUM(TotCount) FOR UserName IN ( [neelam], [snehal] ) )AS PivotTable
 JOIN Totals ON PivotTable.EntryDate = Totals.EntryDate
 ORDER BY PivotTable.EntryDate DESC
```

In your exact case:

```
WITH Totals AS (
    SELECT      EntryDate
                    , SUM(TotCount) AS Total
    FROM        @CandidateCount
    GROUP BY    EntryDate
)

SELECT PivotTable.*
       , Totals.Total
 FROM   ( SELECT    EntryDate ,
                UserName ,
                TotCount
          FROM @CandidateCount AS tbl
        ) AS SourceTable PIVOT
    ( SUM(TotCount) FOR UserName IN ( [neelam], [snehal] ) )AS PivotTable
 JOIN Totals ON PivotTable.EntryDate = Totals.EntryDate
 ORDER BY PivotTable.EntryDate DESC
```